# Transit visa for Dubai

Tags: visas, transit, airport-transfer, dubai, yemeni-citizens

My flight will arrive at DXB (Dubai) from Djibouti and I have a connection flight the same day from DWC (Al Maktoum) to KUL (Kuala Lumpur). I'm a Yemeni national and require visa to enter the UAE.

How I can I obtain a transit visa to get to DWC from DXB?

Comment: I don't want to enter Dubai though, I just wanna catch my flight from DWC since I'll be arriving at dxb, I just hope the airline arrange the transportation

Answer (score 4):

It looks like UAE does [not](http://www.emirates.com/english/plan_book/essential_information/visa_passport_information/uae_visas.aspx) grant citizens of Yemen visa-on-arrival. So, you will have to apply for the visa (and receive it) before hand. However, Yemen is on the list of countries eligible to apply online. Here's the [link](https://www.dubaivisa.net/EK-OnlineVisa/Countries.aspx) for that.